Off -diagonal perturbations of a positive semi-difinite matrix
Does the following statement hold?
For a positive semi-definite(PSD) matrix X, if $rank(X) \ge 2 $, there exists a nonzero off-diagonal matrix D that both X+D, X-D are also PSD.
If it doesn't work, what would be a proper lower bound for the rank constraint?
It seems pretty easy at first sight, but I've been stuck on this for hours. I would appreciate any help, please

What's the definition of "off-diagonal matrix"? Is the zero matrix an off-diagonal matrix? It certainly works.

Assuming you meant for $D$ to be nonzero, then $X$ having full rank, or more generally $X$ having eigenvectors ${v_1, \cdots, v_m}$ with strictly positive eigenvalues, $m \geq 2$, and the span of ${v_1, \cdots, v_m}$ coinciding with the span of $m$ standard basis vectors, would be enough. Not sure whether this works in general.

Yes, I implicitly assumed D is nonzero. I fixed it in the original post.
It is indeed pretty straightforward if X has full rank; I wanted to find the minimal rank requirement

So, please, WHAT IS THE DEFINITION OF OFF-DIAGONAL MATRIX?

It is a nonzero matrix whose diagonal terms are all zero.
